# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I'm new in php and postgres sql. 
I have this issue : "pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "manteau ^

```
$adresse=pg_escape_string($_POST['mail_user']);
if(isset($_POST['mail_user']))
{ 
    $query="INSERT INTO newusers2 (email) VALUES ($adresse)";
    pg_query($con,$query);
}
```

with mail_user = my address email manteau.b...
My table (newusers2) is really simple with only one column (email).

Can someone help me with the query?

Thanks

Comment: try `'$adresse'` instead of `$adresse`

Comment: When a value is string you nedd to use quotes '$adresse' and when a value is number you don´t need quotes just $num

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now!

Comment: shouldn't we remove the mysql tag?

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain Exceedingly bad advice. ESpecially for new users, direct them at parametrised statements ("prepared statements") instead.

Answer (score 2):

Put the value `$adresse` inside quotes:

```
$query="INSERT INTO newusers2 (email) VALUES ('$adresse')";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being incorrect due to lack of quoting your code is also terribly insecure.

```
$query="INSERT INTO newusers2 (email) VALUES ($adresse)";
pg_query($con,$query);
```

Imagine if someone submitted `');DELETE FROM newusers2;--` as their address? Whoops, there goes your user table.

See [the PHP documentation on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [this site](http://bobby-tables.com/) for details.

Use [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) to solve this issue. It's very simple:

```
$query='INSERT INTO newusers2 (email) VALUES ($1)';
pg_query($con,$query,array($adresse));
```

(Note that new code in PHP really should use PDO, though).